# passing ID of Button onClick of Checkbox

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net

how do I pass  ID of Button ,onClick of Checkbox to a function in  external javascript file.The main purpose is to click hidden button on click of checkbox.

here is the code :ASCX Page

```
 <asp:CheckBox ID="chkPriority" runat="server" onclick="submitit('btn')"/>
 <asp:Label runat="server" CssClass="label" ID="lblPriority" Text="Priority"></asp:Label>
 <asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" OnClick="btn_Click" Height="0" Width="0" CssClass="hidden" />
```

External JS File:

```
function submitit(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).click();
}
```

Comment: `onclick="submitit('<%= btn.ClientID %>')"` or `this.form.submit()`

Comment: i tried this..its not working

Comment: @KobyDouek i am getting error saying, document.getelementById is null or empty

Comment: you may want to navigate via the parent: `onclick="$(this).parent().find('button').click()"` or just `onclick="ìf (this.checked) btn_Click()"`

Comment: if you want to hidden button then better create html control not asp control then it will work.

Comment: @mplungjan its not working

Comment: "It is not working" is a useless comment. Console errors? What?

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned in the comments:

> I am getting error saying, document.getelementById is null or empty

This is happening because the `asp:Button` has a different ID than `btn` when rendered on the HTML page.

When using ASCX (Web User Control files), ASP renders the control's IDs like: `ctl00$btn` or `ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btn`.

**Option 1**: pass the `btn` exact client ID:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkPriority" runat="server" onclick="submitit('<%= btn.ClientID %>')"/>
```

**Option 2**: use jQuery, which knows how to handle a rendered ASP control's ID:

```
function submitit(id) {
    $('#' + id).click();
}
```

Comment: Where are you getting this error? In the JS file? in the ASP?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot add parenthesis`()` to the onclick `btn_Click` function

```js
function submitit(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).click()
}
function btn_Click() {
    console.log("Clicked!")
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="chkPriority" runat="server" onclick="submitit('btn')"/>
<button id="btn" runat="server" onclick="btn_Click()" Height="0" Width="0" style="display:none;" />
```

Comment: Read the comments: *"i am getting error saying, document.getelementById is null or empty"*